# Regex for html tags that are not commented

Tags: php, html, regex

I need to find all `<link />` tags in the html which are not commented.

For example, in html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="xyz/dzgt/style.css" />
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xyz/dzgt/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

I need a regexp matching `<link rel="stylesheet" href="xyz/dzgt/style.css"/>` but not matching `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xyz/dzgt/ie7.css" />` because it is surrounded by `<!-- -->`.

I could find all `<link />` tags with the following regex `/<link.*href="(.*\.css)".*\/>/m`, but it also matches the ones are commented, but I only need the ones are not commented.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Using greedy regex `.*` to parse HTML isn't great most of the times. Are you sure you want to use regex ? It might get a little complicated ...

Comment: For those interested in a regex solution, take a look [here](http://regex101.com/r/vV0jK9)

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272).

Answer (score 4):

You should make use of [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Class instead of regex to parse HTML. Check [`this.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1003917)

```
<?php
$html='<link rel="stylesheet" href="xyz/dzgt/style.css" />
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xyz/dzgt/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('link') as $tag) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('href');
   
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
xyz/dzgt/style.css
```

Comment: Yup - every time someone tries to parse HTML/XML with a RegExp, God kills a puppy, fact!